# Java 8, how to compose (Bi)Function from (Bi)Predicate

Tags: java, java-8

I don't believe this question is specific to the `Bi` versions of these Java 8 classes, hence the parens in the question title.

I composed a function to create an `Apache Commons Lang3 Pair` object with the following requirements:

1. If both Left and Right are null, then the Pair should be null
2. If Left and Right are equal to one another, then the Pair should be null
3. Otherwise, a Pair should be created, either side of which may be null

I did this within a method as follows:

```
BiPredicate<String,String> valuesExist = (pre, post) -> pre != null || post != null;

final BiPredicate<String, String> valuesDiffer = valuesExist.and((pre, post) -> 
            (pre != null) ? ! pre.equals(post) : true);

BiFunction<String, String, Pair<String,String>> createPair = 
            (pre, post) -> (valuesDiffer.test(pre, post)) ?
                            ImmutablePair.of(pre, post) : null;  

// usage looks like:
Pair<String, String> myPair = createPair.apply(myValue1, myValue2)
```

I had 3 questions:

1. Is there a way to avoid the 2 BiPredicates?  The second one is only needed because referencing inside the BiFunction requires it to be `final`
2. Is there a way to move this out of the method and into the surrounding class?
3. Is there obvious "clean-up" I missed?

**Update**

Based upon one of the answers below, a solution without any Java-8 features also seems practical:

```
static boolean filterPairArgs(String pre, String post) {
    return (pre != null || post != null) && ((pre == null) || !pre.equals(post));
}

static Pair<String, String> createPair(String v1, String v2) {
    if (filterPairArgs(v1, v2)) {
       return new Pair<>(v1, v2);
    } 
    return null;
}

// usage looks like:
Pair<String, String> myPair = createPair(myValue1, myValue2);
```

Comment: The predicate can be greatly simplified as `(a, b) -> Objects.equals(a, b) ? null : ImmutablePair.of(a, b)`. I'm not sure if there's a reason you wanted to use composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null-safe handling of [Objects.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method will clean things up here.

Personally, I'd put this in a helper function. You can use it functionally as a tidy method reference or simply call it as a method.

```
static Pair<String, String> toPair(String pre, String post) {
  return Objects.equals(pre, post) ? null : ImmutablePair.of(pre, post);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems great!

Comment: I suppose it could return an `Optional<Pair<String,String>>` too, depending on how the caller works.

Comment: this returns `ImmutablePar.of(null, null)` when 2 nulls are passed.

Comment: @Arkadiy No it doesn't.

Comment: @Arkadiy No problem. I am used to `null` comparing negatively to everything (sort of like `NaN`), so it's a little counter-intuitive but comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the predicates:

```
BiPredicate<String,String> valuesExist = (pre, post) -> (pre != null || post != null) && ((pre == null) || !pre.equals(post));
BiFunction<String, String, Pair<String,String>> createPair =
        (pre, post) -> (valuesExist.test(pre, post)) ?
                new Pair<>(pre, post) : null;
```

Personally I would create 2 methods/functions instead:

```
boolean filterPairArgs(String pre, String post) {
    return (pre != null || post != null) && ((pre == null) || !pre.equals(post));
}

Pair<String, String> createPair(String v1, String v2, BiPredicate<String, String> pred) {
    if(pred.test(v1, v2)) {
        return new Pair<>(v1, v2);
    } 
    return null;
}

// usage looks like:
Pair<String, String> myPair = createPair(myValue1, myValue2, this::filterPairArgs);
```

Comment: Changing those both to "static" methods would simplify further - even to the extent of removing all Java-8 vestiges - no?

Comment: With static methods you would use still method references which are a feature of java 8. The decision to make them static or not would require more context. I leave that tou you. Just remember that when you create BiFunctions and BiPredicates you are creating objects that will need to be garbage collected.

Comment: Updated my question to better reflect what I was trying to get at.